# How to show New Product 1st on Category page

Tags: magento-1.9, category-products, new-products

I have added new product and it show at the end of the category page in magento 1.9.2.3. 
Suppose if i have 2 page of category products than new product show at 2nd page at the end, but i want to show the product at 1st place on 1st page.  Anyone know how can i show newly product at 1st place in the category page.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as a programmer, you will not do this if you think you are expert. But, who know, this is a easiest and fastest way to get the system work well, get all of products of all of categories sort by newest products in 5 minutes without any risk. Actually, this is not really “magento core edit”, we just inherit the core code and override it in local directory, it ‘s fine if we update the core.

Now let ‘s copy **app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php** to **app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php** (create a new directory if it is not exists).

Open new file and look at these lines of code in around line 232

```
if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
$this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(), $this->getCurrentDirection());
}
```

Now, replace with these lines

```
if ($this->getCurrentOrder()) {
if(($this->getCurrentOrder())=='position'){
$this->_collection->setOrder('entity_id','desc');
}
else {
$this->_collection->setOrder($this->getCurrentOrder(),$this->getCurrentDirection());
}
}
```

That ‘s all, now remember to clear all cache and reindex too see the magic.

[For more see here.](http://magento2x.com/magento-sort-newest-products-solution/)

Comment: Please accept this answer so that others user can get help from right answer

Comment: Click the checkmark under this post, on the left. ( it's right below the arrows).

Comment: See this image http://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png

Comment: In my category there are 100's of products, how to set selected products placed first page?